# asp localise text

Tags: asp-classic, localization

I am working on asp website with the following code:

```
<div class="btn-continuer"><a href="<%=urlGoBack%>"><span><%=btn_continuer_achats%></span>   </a></div>
```

I am having problem understanding the <%=variablename%> format.

what does this mean? how does this text which appear in the variable correctly displays in different languages.

I have to put another button, but as i am putting into static HTML

, the localisation is not being performed.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string

```
<%=variablename%>
```

is a synonym for

```
<%
  Response.Write variablename
%>
```

which just outputs the contents of variablename, nothing more. You must ensure to put the right string into "variablename" yourself.

Classic ASP has no builtin means of localized strings. You can use the SetLocale command to localize Numbers, Date values, etc. ([see here](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13969.asp)), but this will not help you for strings like button captions.

EDIT: This might help you to find a solution for string translation using a XML resource file: http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2006/06/02/resource-files-for-classic-asp/

Comment: Hello gpinkas. thank your for your response, it helped me to understand the variable. I found a possible solution: the variable: btn_continuer_achats is stored in different asp files. for eg. in lang-fr.asp, the variable is assigned the string in French etc..